# Difference between startChooser() method and startActivity()

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

I'm new to android and i have noticed that i can share an intent in 2 ways.

**first way :**

`ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this).
                setType(mimeType).
                setChooserTitle(title).
                setText(text).
                startChooser();`

**second way is:**

```
Intent shareIntent =   ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
                                                .setChooserTitle(title)
                                                .setType(mimeType)
                                                .setText(text)
                                                .getIntent();
    if (shareIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
        startActivity(shareIntent);
    }
```

my question is ,does using `startChooser()` saves me from the check that i use in the second way? ..also is there any other differences between these two functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does using `startChooser()` saves me from the check that i use in the
>   second?

No.

IntentBuilder is basically a helper class for constructing  sharing intents(`Intent#ACTION_SEND` and `Intent#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`) and starting activities to share content.

> also is there any other differences between these two functions

Under the hood, both `startChooser()` and startActivity() perform same action. `startChooser()` just wraps `startActivity()`. Check out the definition of `startChooser()`:

```
    /**
     * Start a chooser activity for the current share intent.
     *
     * <p>Note that under most circumstances you should use
     * {@link ShareCompat#configureMenuItem(MenuItem, IntentBuilder)
     *  ShareCompat.configureMenuItem()} to add a Share item to the menu while
     * presenting a detail view of the content to be shared instead
     * of invoking this directly.</p>
     */
     public void startChooser() {
        mActivity.startActivity(createChooserIntent());
     }
```

I would recommend you to use second approach, which gives you better control with which you can handle the error scenario and present meaningful information to the user.

Answer (score 0):

> First way :

Here you give your Intent to framework but you do not know if any application is available in device to handle that Intent or not.

> second way :

You first make sure that at-least one application is available in device which can handle the Intent.

In second way you have a way to handle unexpected-flow without passing that intent to framework. Like you can notify user about "no application available to handle that action".